# NameError: class name is not defined

Tags: python

I can't find why this piece of code won't work:

```
class Agent:
def hello(self, first_name):
    return "Bien le bonjour" + first_name + "!"
agent = Agent()
print(agent.hello("Félix"))
```

I'm pretty sure to run it under python3 since i just follow [a tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-ubuntu-16-04)
on how to create a local envirement for python3.

It return

```
    class Agent:
  File "la_poo_avec_python-00_setup/model.py", line 4, in Agent
    agent = Agent()
NameError: name 'Agent' is not defined
(my_env) noob@Flex:~/Noobi/prog/python3env/my_env$
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to show your indentation correctly? It may be important. (My guess is that `agent = Agent()` is indented as if it's the contents of the class, and it shouldn't be)

Comment: I'm sorry what do you want me to edit ?

Comment: Are you doing this in the interpreter or a script? Can you do `print(dir())` and paste the output here?

Comment: Working fine for me in IDLE.  I indented your `def hello` and `return` statements properly (they are wrong in the posted question), and received no errors.

Comment: @FélixBernard Edit the question. There should be a small grey "edit" link at the bottom of it. Make the indentation look as it looks in your real code. (The easiest way is to paste your real code in the press the "{}" button in the editor)

Comment: @Shiva : It does nothing... I think i'm runing a script but in the interpreter its the same.

Comment: @DavidW The identation is this one, i paste it as is it is

Comment: @FélixBernard It isn't, because the indentation shown in the question gives a different error: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Comment: @DavidW it was what you expected. In my text editor the agent and print line was under def.

Comment: @DavidW For future reference, the traceback says `class Agent:` and `in Agent`, which means the next part, `agent = Agent()`, is running in the class scope, confirming you're correct.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is correct, but I suspect there is something wrong with the indentation. This is how it should be

```
class Agent:
    def hello(self, first_name):
        return "Bien le bonjour" + first_name + "!"
agent = Agent()
print(agent.hello("Félix"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you used sounds correct, but you need to make some corrections:

- You need to separate your class from the main code as below because interpreter thinks that the line 4 and what is after that belong to your class:

```
class Agent:
    def hello(self, first_name):
        return "Bien le bonjour" + first_name + "!"

agent = Agent()
print(agent.hello("Felix"))
```

- You may have to replace "l'accent aigu" with "e" in "Felix" as it can reflect you an error regarding using "Non-ASCII" character in the code.
- Indentation is another error that I got from you code. So, please make sure it is organized properly before running.

Comment: Python3 defaults to UTF-8, not ASCII. And while the separation of the class from the rest of the code is crucial for readability, it’s not the cause of the error — the indentation alone is. And there’s already an answer explaining this.

Comment: I had this same exact error with defining and using a class in Python, correcting the indentation fixed the error, indentation is very important in Python, no surprises here.

Answer (score -2):

The class needs an __init__ method. As other answers suggest, fix the indention and do this:

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def hello(self, first_name):
        return "Bien le bonjour" + first_name + "!"
```

Comment: Why would it need an `__init__` that does nothing? `__init__` is not mandatory, if that's what you thought; there's always `object.__init__` to fall back on.